# How to structure limited voting system design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-normalization

I have 3 types of tables. `Categories`, `Candidates`, `Voters`.
To be describing the problem as short as possible, `Candidates` can belong to only 1 category. `Voters` can vote for each category and only one person from a category. There can not be second person to vote for 1 category. I mean, If Voter votes for Paul, which Paul is a candidate for President, the same voter can not vote for a second presidential candidate, but can vote for Vice President and Secretary.
So the main problem is creating a structure for **1 Voter can vote for 3 types of categories and for only 1 candidate inside of the category**

Here are the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Categories(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE Candidates(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Surname NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Category_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Categories(Id) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Voters(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Surname NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NOT NULL  CHECK(Age>=18),
);
```

Here is the table which I encountered with the problem on

```
CREATE TABLE VotersCandidates(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Voter_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voters(Id) NOT NULL,
    Category_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Categories(Id) NOT NULL,
    Candidate_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Candidates(Id) NOT NULL,
);
```

Thank you to lend a hand!

Comment: There's no uniqueness constraint on Candidates or Voters.  Should there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key on `VoterCandidates` is fine.  What you are describing is a unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE VotersCandidates (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Voter_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voters(Id) NOT NULL,
    Category_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Categories(Id) NOT NULL,
    Candidate_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Candidates(Id) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unq_VotersCandidates_Voter_Category UNIQUE (Voter_Id, Category_Id)
);
```

Now, you have another issue . . . it is possible for the category in this table to be inconsistent with the category in the candidates table.  To fix that, use another unique constraint and foreign key reference:

```
CREATE TABLE Candidates (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Surname NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Category_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Categories(Id) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unq_Candidates_Candidate_Category UNIQUE (Category_Id, id)
);
```

Then use this for the foreign key relationship in the votes table:

```
CREATE TABLE VotersCandidates (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Voter_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Voters(Id) NOT NULL,
    Category_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Categories(Id) NOT NULL,
    Candidate_Id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_voterscandidates_candidates FOREIGN KEY (Category_Id, Candidate_Id) REFERENCES Candidates (Category_Id, Id) 
    CONSTRAINT unq_VotersCandidates_Voter_Category UNIQUE (Voter_Id, Category_Id)
);
```

And one final comment.  I recommend naming the primary key after the table.  So instead of `candidates.id`, it would be `candidates.candidate_id`.  That way, the foreign key relationships are usually on columns with the same name -- a form of self-documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of your existing primary key on the VotersCandidates table. Instead, implement this primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE VotersCandidates
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_VotCat PRIMARY KEY (Voter_Id,Category_Id);
```

This ensures that each voter can vote in exactly one category.